# Is there such thing as a .virc for the vi editor?

Tags: vi

I know that you can modify Vim with a .vimrc.  Does Vi , the older version of Vim, have a .virc?  If so, where can I find info on it?  I am trying to turn on line numbers permanently instead of activating them every time I go into vi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

vi should read configuration commands in a `.exrc` file, if it exists, in your home directory.

This should be documented in `man vi` but you can check [OReilly](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/lnut/ch11_14.htm)